# Gson deserialize fields and create objects

Tags: java, android, json

I'm using `Gson` to handle json.
I'm receiving a json in this format:

```
{
  "name": "Paul Matt",
  "age": "120",
  "phone": "00123456789",
  "email": "paul@matt.com"
}
```

I cannot change the format of this json.

If deserializing to this class:

```
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
public String name;
@SerializedName("age")
@Expose
public String age;
@SerializedName("phone")
@Expose
public String phone;
@SerializedName("email")
@Expose
public String email;
```

But what I really want is that the json is deserialized to a class like this one:

```
public Person person; //name and age goes here
public PersonContacts contacts; // email and phone goes here
```

Whats the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you should parse your JSON manually.
In Gson library we have two possibilities for achieving this:

1. Create `streaming` deserializer and parse every token;
2. Create implementation of `JsonDeserializer` and parse ready `JsonElement` object.

Here some examples:

**The first approach**:

```
public class StreamUserDeserializer extends TypeAdapter<User> {

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, List<CMPoint> value) throws IOException {

    }

    @Override
    public User read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        User user = new User();

        in.beginObject();
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            switch (in.nextName()) {
                case "name":
                    user.getPerson().setName(in.nextString());
                    break;

                case "age":
                    user.getPerson().setAge(in.nextInt());
                    break;

                case "phone":
                    user.getPersonContacts().setPhone(in.nextString());
                    break;

                case "email":
                    user.getPersonContacts().setEmail(in.nextString());
                    break;

                default:
                    in.skipValue();
            }
        }
        in.endObject();

        return user;
    }

}
```

**The second approach**:

```
public class JsonElementUserDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<User> {

    @Override
    public User deserialize(final JsonElement json, final Type typeOfT, final JsonDeserializationContext context)
  throws JsonParseException {
      JsonObject userObject = json.getAsJsonObject();

      User user = new User();
      user.getPerson().setName(userObject.get("name").getAsString());
      user.getPerson().setAge(userObject.get("age").getAsInt());
      user.getPersonContacts().setPhone(userObject.get("phone").getAsString());
      user.getPersonContacts().setAge(userObject.get("email").getAsString());
      return user;
   }
}
```